# regex Javascript substring

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string

```
Sun-Sep-20-2015-19:11:53-GMT+0300
```

I want to find the delete all the string after the 19:11..
so the string will be only

```
Sun-Sep-20-2015
```

I have to search in regex the first 4 number and remove from them..
I know that I can search for 2015 but it can be also 2016..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a capturing group:

```
var str = 'Sun-Sep-20-2015-19:11:53-GMT+0300';

var result = str.replace(/^(.+?\d{4}).*$/m, '$1');
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pK1qC7/2)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of removing things from the string, you can pick out the part that you want:

```js
var time = 'Sun-Sep-20-2015-19:11:53-GMT+0300';

var date = /^(.+?-.+?-\d+-\d+)/.exec(time)[0];

// show result in snippet
document.write(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a capture group to get what you want

check out this pattern `(\w.+\d):`

See demo here https://regex101.com/r/uJ0vD4/5